# MVC RadioButtonFor group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, radiobuttonfor

I have a class for a PDF

```
public class UIClonePDFDetail
    {
        public int CatalogueID { get; set; }

        public List<PDF> PDFToClone { get; set; }

    }
```

The pdf class is:

```
public class PDF
    {
        public int ID{ get; set; }

        public bool Selected{ get; set; }

    }
```

I am trying to create a list of radiobuttons for the user to select 1 and this sets the selected property on the PDF element in the PDFToClone  list.

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.UIClonePDFDetail[Model.UIClonePDFDetail.IndexOf(stageSelection)].Selected, "stageSelection")
```

But this allows nultiple selection of radio buttons. I can see why this is happening, because the name elements of the Html tags are different. Is there a way of forcing them into the same family?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[RadioButtonFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobuttonfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) contains an overload that accepts HTML attributes. You can create an anonymous type and include the Name attribute like this:

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.UIClonePDFDetail[Model.UIClonePDFDetail
          .IndexOfstageSelection)].Selected, "stageSelection", new { Name = "grp" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use:

```
Html.RadioButtonFor(model => 
    Model.UIClonePDFDetail[Model.UIClonePDFDetail.IndexOf(stageSelection)].Selected,
    "stageSelection")
```

instead of:

```
Html.CheckBoxFor(model => 
    Model.UIClonePDFDetail[Model.UIClonePDFDetail.IndexOf(stageSelection)].Selected, 
   "stageSelection")
```

Comment: Sorry, i was using radiobuttonfor, it was a typo. Still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass htmlAttributes with the group of the radiobutton, with something like:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.UIClonePDFDetail[Model.UIClonePDFDetail
      .IndexOfstageSelection)].Selected, "stageSelection", new { Group = "A" })
```